# Relatively positioned hover menu behaves in Chrome/FF, breaks in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu that "opens" when someone hovers a certain nav item. By "opening" it, it just adds or removes the class "hidden" with jQuery .hidden is just visibility:hidden. In order for it to show up on top of the main welcome image (the menu is transparent and covers exactly the space of the header image), it's positioned relatively within a 0px by 0px reference div.

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#products_open_link").mouseenter(function(event) {
        $("#products_menu").css("width",$("#header_img").width());
        $("#products_menu").css("height",$("#header_img").height());
        $("#products_menu").removeClass("hidden");
    });
    $("#products_open_link").mouseleave(function(event) {
        if ($('#products_menu').is(':hover')) {
            $("#products_menu").mouseleave(function(event) {
                $("#products_menu").addClass("hidden");
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#products_menu").addClass("hidden");
        };
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="reference_point" style="max-width:0px;max-height:0px;">
    <div id="products_menu" class="hidden part_of_menu hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <div class="products_menu_padding">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <ul>
                        <strong>Metal Forming</strong>
                        <li><a href="#">Stamping</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wire &amp; Tube</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Coin-Pierce-Trim</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fasteners &amp; Rivets</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <ul>
                        <strong>Welding</strong>
                        <li><a href="#">Resistance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MIG</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <ul>
                        <strong>Coating</strong>
                        <li><a href="#">Powder</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">E-Coating</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <ul>
                        <strong><a href="#">Prototype/Short Order</a></strong>
                        <strong><a href="#">Quality</a></strong>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="img/header_2.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="header_img">
</div>
```

Works fine in Chrome and FF. In IE, it appears and all BUT the header image is displaced downward like 200px. So the transparent menu is where it should be, but it causes the header image to move downward and that also makes the menu not cover the header image. I'm new to js/jQuery so that might be messy but it does what it should. I just wanna know how to fix it messing up in IE.

[Here is how it looks in IE](http://i.gyazo.com/e75435caf2a3e119847949d4451541cf.png)

[Here is how it looks in Chrome/FF](http://i.gyazo.com/456c7adc60f4c06e8ba735ee01c5cda6.png)

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle or codepen link?

Comment: it's not your jquery, it's your css that's wrong for IE, share your css code.

Comment: `#products_menu {
 background:rgba(37, 41, 87, 0.8);
 position:relative;
 z-index:100;
 bottom:0;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 display:block;
}`